# Pegar a ultima ocorrência num string javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho um string contendo o seguinte:

```
xx_xxxxx_0001_ABCDE_TESTE_INTRODUCAO_VIDEO
```

Como eu pegaria sempre a última palavra depois do underline "_" ?

O resultado esperado seria:

```
VIDEO
```

Answer (score 13):

Basta usar [lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) que retorna a posição da última ocorrência de uma *string*:

```js
var texto = "xx_xxxxx_0001_ABCDE_TESTE_INTRODUCAO_VIDEO";
var ultima = texto.substring(texto.lastIndexOf("_")+1);
console.log(ultima);
```

Para o cenário da pergunta fica bem simples, mas para outras situações o `indexOf` ou o `split` como demostrou o Leonardo Bosquett podem ser alternativas.

Comment: Legal que também pode usar `.slice` em vez de `.substring`. Vou dar +1 pra vc ganhar a medalha. :D

Comment: Legal que um problema simples gerou respostas bem interessantes e várias opções

Answer (score 8):

Basta utilizar [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) e pegar a última posição do array utilizando [pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop):

```js
let v = "xx_xxxxx_0001_ABCDE_TESTE_INTRODUCAO_VIDEO".split("_").pop();
console.log(v);
```

Notas:

- Não tem validações de código
- A utilização do split é melhor aproveitada se você utilizar os outros valores do array que é retornado, se o necessário for apenas a **última palavra** utilize [lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) e [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) como demonstrado na resposta do Ricardo Pontual.

Comment: Podes fazer numa só linha `let ultimaPalavra = "xx_xxxxx_0001_ABCDE_TESTE_INTRODUCAO_VIDEO".split("_").pop();`

Comment: Deixei o negativo porque considero que, a menos que será utilizado a lista de todas as palavras separadas por `_`, fazer o `split` é adicionar complexidade desnecessária - seria como construir um prédio ao lado de uma árvore frutífera afim de usar o elevador para colher o fruto ao invés de usar uma escada.

Comment: @Leite bem lembrado, acho o pop mais correto também

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss existem outras alternativas, como indexof e substring, que podem fazer isso melhor e também trabalham melhor quando existir validações da string de entrada, mas a resposta do Ricardo já tem essa alternativa

Comment: @LeonardoBosquett Exatamente. Eu acho extremamente válido responder com alternativas de soluções, mesmo quando não são as melhores, desde que seja respondido, também, quais seriam as condições em que tal alternativa deveria ser cogitada. A pergunta pede apenas a última palavra, então eu não cogitaria criar uma lista com todas elas apenas para buscar a última (por isso meu voto, como comentei); porém, se na resposta você explicasse que num contexto que seriam utilizadas todas as palavras, poderia ser feito de tal forma, seria uma resposta muito mais completa.

Comment: Acho bom que haja alternativas, até mesmo para o OP as ficar a conhecer. Eu gosto demasiado de arrays, portanto era capaz de escolher esta solução. Em termos de performance, estas são idênticas, mas é um exemplo bem simples. EDIT: Usando os métodos do string para pesquisar a ultima palavra é mais rápido que transformar num array.

Comment: Já agora, deixo o teste, só por curiosidade. http://jsben.ch/hBfi6

Comment: Removi o voto após a edição, mas acho conveniente deixar os comentários, pois estão diretamente relacionados ao contexto da resposta.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss também concordo em manter, obrigado pela sugestão

Answer (score 5):

Apenas para dar mais uma possibilidade, também pode fazer com uma regex simples. Não quer isto dizer que seja melhor que as já boas alternativas mostradas, e provavelmente será menos eficiente também.

A regex seria:

```
_([^_]*)$
```

Explicação:

```
_       - underline
([^_]*) - seguido de qualquer quantidade de carateres que não underline
$       - seguido de fim da linha
```

Exemplo:

```js
let texto = "xx_xxxxx_0001_ABCDE_TESTE_INTRODUCAO_VIDEO";
let ultimo = texto.match(/_([^_]*)$/)[1];

console.log(ultimo);
```

Com o [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) obtenho o conteudo do primeiro grupo de captura, o que está dentro de `(` e `)` acedendo à posição `1`.

Comment: Legal essa resposta, sabia que daria pra fazer, mas meus conhecimentos em *regular expressions* são limitados :)

Comment: Acho interessante esta solução, embora caia na teoria _escada-elevador_ do @AndersonCarlosWoss :D...